# Why is a python aws lambda with a lambda layer containing scikit-learn and pandas failing with `error importing numpy`?

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a python 3.9 lambda function which uses scikit-learn and pandas to run a model.

I am creating a lambda layer (I create the layer in a docker container using the base image `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9`) which contains these packages in a `python/` directory.

Before zipping I remove some files so as to reduce the size of the layer. This is required so I get under the lambda unzipped limit. To do this I run the following commands:

```
rm -rf *.dist-info
find . -name "tests" -type d | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
find . -name "docs" -type d | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
find . -name "__pycache__" -type d | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
```

I zip this and upload it as a lambda layer to AWS. I attach this lambda layer to my lambda but when I try to execute I get the following error:

```
Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

Can anyone help me understand why this error occurs? The directory structure of the lambda layer is as specified in the AWS docs so I've ruled that out as a problem. Maybe some of the files I am removing are of importance but I didn't think so in this case